# QuickSort - Issue while taking pivot as starting element

Tags: java, quicksort

I was trying for hours.  For the below code, if we give input as 6-digits, {7, 12, 3, 1, 5, 6}, but for this input {7, 12, 3, 1, 5, 6,2};, it give a Stack overflow exception. Plz suggest me on this.

```
package divideandconquer;

import utils.PrintUtil;

public class QuickSortLomatos_StartFromFirst {
    public void doSort(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if(start<end) {
            int pivotIndex = getPivot(arr, start, end);
                doSort(arr, start, pivotIndex - 1);
                doSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, end);
        }
    }

    public int getPivot(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = arr[start];
        int i=0, j=0;
        while(i<=j && j < end) {
            j++;
            if(arr[j] < pivot) {
                i++;
                swap(arr, i, j);
            }
        }
        swap(arr, start, i);
        return i;
    }
    public void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{7, 12, 3, 1, 5, 6};
        QuickSortLomatos_StartFromFirst qs = new QuickSortLomatos_StartFromFirst();
        qs.doSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        PrintUtil.doPrint(arr);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's in your `utils.PrintUtil`? I've run your code with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));` instead of `PrintUtil.doPrint(arr);`  and I get no error.

Comment: Just iterates over array and print the values. Nothing much there..so didn’t include it

Comment: If you do not include it, it's not possible to run the code as you run it., see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I take it back.. it does go to an error. You included the initialization that works, instead of the one that doesn't. I think you should edit your post though, so it doesn't rely on things that is not included.

Comment: Sorry, included it below:

Comment: package utils;

public class PrintUtil {
    public static void doPrint(int[] elements) {
        for(int i =0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(elements[i]+",");
        }
    }
}

Comment: Kindly edit your post, do not add clarifications in comments :) Also include the actual error. You don't need the include the repeating parts though.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the google searches I found, the solution, by modifying my partition function as below.

```
public int getPivot(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = arr[start];
        int i=start+1, j=start+1;
        while(j<=(end)) {
            if(arr[j] < pivot) {
                swap(arr, i, j);
                i++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        swap(arr, start, i-1);
        return i-1;
    }
```

I need to check...my previous flow, what happened wrong. Tku.